# BroadcastReceiver in custom view

Tags: android, view, broadcastreceiver

I need to create a view to show battery status. I made a custom view (extends from LinearLayout) and registered BroadcastReceiver in constructor.

When i need to call unregisterreceiver method? in finalize? Where is android View lifecycle?

Thanks

Comment: why u are using broadcast receiver in view

Comment: that is not a good idea i guess.

Comment: you have to use some sette method for that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onDetachToWindow` could be the place.

> This is called when the view is detached from a window. At this point
>   it no longer has a surface for drawing.

In my opinion you should put your `BroadCastReceiver` in the `Activity`/`Fragment` and handle the `View`'s update from there

Comment: Yes, i moved my code in a fragment and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Just want to add that in custom view it is better to subscribe in `onAttachedToWindow`, because view [can be created (e.g. inflated) but never attached](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/android-leak-pattern-subscriptions-in-views-18f0860aa74c#.y2fjp5zyo), so leak may happen. 
Also `onWindowVisibilityChanged` may be useful.